# iBus not working on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ibus

I have done all the steps to write in Hangul (Korean). But I have had no luck. I have used Ubuntu for 2 years now and iBus has worked on other versions of Ubuntu. Just not 13.04. The weird things is is that it works in the dash. I can search in Korean. I just can't type in Korean anywhere else.

Does anyone know the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  For me it's breaking down in libX11-6 with Python-3 in ibus japanese input.  I've filed a bug report against it.  Not an answer but at least you know you're not alone.  Works fine on my 12.10 system...